# Not able to run restapi web service on localhost

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, rest, tomcat

I have created mine first restapi on localhost.

Here is my code:

```
package RestClient;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/RestClient")
public class Restwebclient {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
    public String sayXMLHello() {
        return "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>" + "<hello> Hello Its my first Rest API" + "</hello>";
    }

}
```

Web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <display-name>Webservice</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
<servlet-name>JAVA WS</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>

<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>RestClient</param-value>
</init-param>   
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>


<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>JAVA WS</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>  

</web-app>
```

Tomcat Server ports:

```
Tomcat admin port: 8005
HTTP/1.1: 8080
AJP/1.3: 8009
```

When I run this, I get an error like this

```
Several ports (8005, 8080, 8009) required by Tomcat v8.5 Server at localhost are already in use. The server may already be running in another process, or a system process may be using the port. To start this server you will need to stop the other process or change the port number(s).
```

Then I created new ports,

```
Tomcat admin port: 8002
HTTP/1.1: 8001
AJP/1.3: 8003
```

Got error like this:

```
 Server Tomcat v8.5 Server at localhost failed to start.
```

Googled, then found out, what ever port I'm mentioning in eclipse, should be present in httpd confg file. But this not present in Apache installation folder.

I found one more info that, there is an file named as server.xml where we can change the ports. But am not able to save that file with changes no matter what.

Can anyone tell me please what's wrong happening ?

Logs info:localhost_access_log.2017-09-09.log

```
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [09/Sep/2017:18:52:48 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11452
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [09/Sep/2017:18:52:48 +0530] "GET /tomcat.png HTTP/1.1" 200 5103
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [09/Sep/2017:18:52:48 +0530] "GET /tomcat.css HTTP/1.1" 200 5931
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [09/Sep/2017:18:52:48 +0530] "GET /bg-nav.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1401
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [09/Sep/2017:18:52:48 +0530] "GET /bg-middle.png HTTP/1.1" 200 1918
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [09/Sep/2017:18:52:48 +0530] "GET /bg-upper.png HTTP/1.1" 200 3103
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [09/Sep/2017:18:52:48 +0530] "GET /asf-logo-wide.svg HTTP/1.1" 200 26726
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [09/Sep/2017:18:52:48 +0530] "GET /bg-button.png HTTP/1.1" 200 713
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [09/Sep/2017:18:52:48 +0530] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 200 21630
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [09/Sep/2017:18:58:15 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11452
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [09/Sep/2017:18:58:17 +0530] "GET /manager/status HTTP/1.1" 401 2536
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [09/Sep/2017:18:58:24 +0530] "GET /manager/status HTTP/1.1" 401 2536
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [09/Sep/2017:18:58:25 +0530] "GET /manager/status HTTP/1.1" 401 2536
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [09/Sep/2017:19:47:46 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11452
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [09/Sep/2017:19:48:17 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11452
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [09/Sep/2017:20:01:45 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11452
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [09/Sep/2017:20:01:46 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11452
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [09/Sep/2017:20:03:03 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11452
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [09/Sep/2017:20:03:25 +0530] "GET /manager/status HTTP/1.1" 401 2536
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [09/Sep/2017:21:32:26 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11452
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [09/Sep/2017:21:42:20 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11452
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [09/Sep/2017:21:42:23 +0530] "GET /manager/status HTTP/1.1" 401 2536
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [09/Sep/2017:21:47:00 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11452
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [09/Sep/2017:21:47:01 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11452
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [09/Sep/2017:21:47:01 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11452
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [09/Sep/2017:21:47:01 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11452
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [09/Sep/2017:21:47:02 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11452
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [09/Sep/2017:21:47:02 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11452
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [09/Sep/2017:21:47:02 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11452
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [09/Sep/2017:21:47:02 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11452
0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 - - [09/Sep/2017:21:47:03 +0530] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 11452
```

catalina.2.017-09-09.log

```
09-Sep-2017 14:13:05.928 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.20
09-Sep-2017 14:13:05.930 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Aug 2 2017 21:35:49 UTC
09-Sep-2017 14:13:05.930 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.5.20.0
09-Sep-2017 14:13:05.930 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows 7
09-Sep-2017 14:13:05.930 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            6.1
09-Sep-2017 14:13:05.931 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
09-Sep-2017 14:13:05.931 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_73
09-Sep-2017 14:13:05.931 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_73-b02
09-Sep-2017 14:13:05.931 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
09-Sep-2017 14:13:05.931 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5
09-Sep-2017 14:13:05.931 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5
09-Sep-2017 14:13:05.931 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5
09-Sep-2017 14:13:05.931 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5
09-Sep-2017 14:13:05.931 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\temp
09-Sep-2017 14:13:05.932 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
09-Sep-2017 14:13:05.932 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\conf\logging.properties
09-Sep-2017 14:13:05.932 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: exit
09-Sep-2017 14:13:05.932 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xms128m
09-Sep-2017 14:13:05.933 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xmx256m
09-Sep-2017 14:13:05.933 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Informatica\9.0.1\clients\tools\datadirect;C:\Informatica\9.0.1\clients\DeveloperClient\bin;C:\Informatica\9.0.1\tools\datadirect;C:\app\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin;C:\Program Files\mysql\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\;C:\Python27;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;;.]
09-Sep-2017 14:13:06.488 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
09-Sep-2017 14:13:06.786 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
09-Sep-2017 14:13:06.788 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
09-Sep-2017 14:13:06.790 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
09-Sep-2017 14:13:06.791 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 1623 ms
09-Sep-2017 14:13:06.873 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
09-Sep-2017 14:13:06.874 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.20
09-Sep-2017 14:13:06.928 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\docs]
09-Sep-2017 14:13:07.545 WARNING [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase.createSecureRandom Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [106] milliseconds.
09-Sep-2017 14:13:07.574 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\docs] has finished in [646] ms
09-Sep-2017 14:13:07.575 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\manager]
09-Sep-2017 14:13:07.648 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\manager] has finished in [73] ms
09-Sep-2017 14:13:07.648 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\ROOT]
09-Sep-2017 14:13:07.674 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\ROOT] has finished in [26] ms
09-Sep-2017 14:13:07.678 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
09-Sep-2017 14:13:07.688 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
09-Sep-2017 14:13:07.691 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 900 ms
09-Sep-2017 20:11:14.438 INFO [Thread-6] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
09-Sep-2017 20:11:14.620 INFO [Thread-6] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
09-Sep-2017 20:11:14.797 INFO [Thread-6] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal Stopping service [Catalina]
09-Sep-2017 20:11:14.869 INFO [Thread-6] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
09-Sep-2017 20:11:14.883 INFO [Thread-6] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
09-Sep-2017 21:32:21.436 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.20
09-Sep-2017 21:32:21.440 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Aug 2 2017 21:35:49 UTC
09-Sep-2017 21:32:21.440 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.5.20.0
09-Sep-2017 21:32:21.440 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows 7
09-Sep-2017 21:32:21.440 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            6.1
09-Sep-2017 21:32:21.440 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
09-Sep-2017 21:32:21.441 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_73
09-Sep-2017 21:32:21.441 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_73-b02
09-Sep-2017 21:32:21.441 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
09-Sep-2017 21:32:21.441 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5
09-Sep-2017 21:32:21.441 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5
09-Sep-2017 21:32:21.441 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5
09-Sep-2017 21:32:21.441 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5
09-Sep-2017 21:32:21.442 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\temp
09-Sep-2017 21:32:21.442 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
09-Sep-2017 21:32:21.442 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\conf\logging.properties
09-Sep-2017 21:32:21.442 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: exit
09-Sep-2017 21:32:21.442 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xms128m
09-Sep-2017 21:32:21.442 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xmx256m
09-Sep-2017 21:32:21.443 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Informatica\9.0.1\clients\tools\datadirect;C:\Informatica\9.0.1\clients\DeveloperClient\bin;C:\Informatica\9.0.1\tools\datadirect;C:\app\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_60\bin;C:\Program Files\mysql\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\;C:\Python27;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\bin\bin;.]
09-Sep-2017 21:32:21.592 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
09-Sep-2017 21:32:21.674 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
09-Sep-2017 21:32:21.676 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
09-Sep-2017 21:32:21.678 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
09-Sep-2017 21:32:21.679 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 686 ms
09-Sep-2017 21:32:21.703 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
09-Sep-2017 21:32:21.704 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.20
09-Sep-2017 21:32:21.713 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\docs]
09-Sep-2017 21:32:22.148 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\docs] has finished in [435] ms
09-Sep-2017 21:32:22.149 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\manager]
09-Sep-2017 21:32:22.217 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\manager] has finished in [68] ms
09-Sep-2017 21:32:22.218 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\ROOT]
09-Sep-2017 21:32:22.242 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 8.5\webapps\ROOT] has finished in [24] ms
09-Sep-2017 21:32:22.246 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
09-Sep-2017 21:32:22.259 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
09-Sep-2017 21:32:22.262 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 583 ms
```

Comment: Could you post the tomcat startup log ? That could help

Comment: @gtosto, please check now, posted logs

Comment: I am sorry  I may have misunderstood your question. Looking at the last line of catalina's log seems that server correctly started up (in 583 ms). So what's the issue ?

Comment: @gtosto, I'm getting error like this with new ports. "Server Tomcat v8.5 Server at localhost failed to start." Secondly, I'm not able to see running server on browser "http://localhost:8001/". Third, If everything is running okay, then why am not able to see the result on url "http://localhost:8001/RestClient" ?

Comment: watching the catalina.2.017-09-09.log i can say:
 - catalina is listening on the 8080 port for http request
 - it seems to me that there is no RestClient webapp deployed.
 - it seems that only the manager and "ROOT" webapp are deployed

Comment: @gtosto, but if you see my code, Don't you think so it should work ? Did I miss anything  ?

Comment: @gtosto, My apache server is running now, but am not able to see me output on localhost:9999/Webservice/RestClient. Its showing 404 not found error ..why is it so ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154059/discussion-between-gtosto-and-learnjava).

Answer (score -1):

just change,i used to do this, change it to 8006 8088 8008 then save,then ok!
In xml file or double click service both ok to change it is ok!